# From apache to nginx url rewrite ( /* to index.html /$1/$2/* to /$1/$2/index.html )

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, single-page-application

Hello I try to migrate from apache to nginx but I stuck on URL Rewriting.

This is for a NUXT SPA application.

With apache I use .htaccess to make the url rewrite.
But unfortunately no htaccess on nginx...

Here is the expected result:

- `website.com/` ---> `/index.html`
- `website.com/ch/en` ---> `/ch/en/index.html`
- `website.com/ch/en/about-us` ---> `/ch/en/index.html`
- `website.com/ch/en/property/328383` ---> `/ch/en/index.html`
- `website.com/toto/lala` ---> `/index.html`
- `website.com/ch` ----> `/index.html`
- `website.com/_nuxt/file.js` ---> `/_nuxt/file.js`
- `website.com/data/file.jpeg` ---> `/data/file.jpeg`

Noted that there are a lot of different countries and languages so I think that manually writing all rewrites is not an option.

My folder structure is like below:

```
dist/
  .htaccess
  index.html
  _nuxt/
     (nuxt generated files)
  data/
     (static file like image, json, etc...)
  ch/
    fr/
      .htaccess
      index.html
    de/
      .htaccess
      index.html
  be/
     fr/
       .htaccess
       index.html

...
```

My root .htaccess contain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in my subfolder, for example /ch/en

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ch/en
  RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /ch/en/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

At the moment i try followings rules on nginx.conf

```
...
location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location /$1/$2/ {
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/index.html;
}
...
```

But url rewrinting not working as expected:
for example `/ch/en` display well `/ch/en/index.html`
but `/ch/en/mypage` display `/index.html` instead of `/ch/en/index.html`

So how can I make rewrite like `/*` -> `/index.html` and  `/$1/$2/` -> `/$1/$2/index.html` on nginx.conf ?

Comment: Where are requests for non-existing folders like `/aa/bb/...` should go?

Comment: To root index.html with a 404 header status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
location / {
    index      index.html index.htm;
    try_files  $uri /index.html;
}
location ~ ^(/[^/]+/[^/]+) {
    index      index.html index.htm;
    try_files  $uri $1/index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to work well except for the urls with only one depth level. Like for example: website.com/ch (There is a 406 Forbidden Error). Any idea how to rewrite 1 level deep to root index ?

Comment: @ZecKa What happens if you remove `$uri/` fragment from the first `try_files` directive?

Comment: Yea now website.com/ch go to index.html fine ! Juste one last thing. website.com/ch/en  (without last "/") go to root index instead of /ch/en/index.html

Comment: Change `^(/[^/]+/[^/]+)/` to `^(/[^/]+/[^/]+)`, but re-check all possible URI combinations after that.

Comment: Okay, now it's working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help! I edit your answer to add your comments corrections ! After I will mark as accepted answer